# JSF 2.0 - Two interfaces for mobile and PC browsers

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm developing an application which requires two interfaces - one for mobile phones browsers and another one for normal PC browsers. The second interface needs to present more information and have a few more functions. of course, both of them are in the same project and use the same beans, etc. It os just the presentation layer which changes. For the time being, I have just the interface for mobile phones. It is accessible when I choose the address: //ip-address:8080/App/ but not when I try to go directly to the page with that interface: //ip-address:8080/App/page.jsp. I got the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An
>   exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /page.jsp at line 30
>
> javax.faces.context.FacesContext
>   context =
>   javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
>   30:
>   context.getViewRoot().setLocale(newLocale);
>   31: %> 32:  33:
>
> Stacktrace:
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    org.apache.jsp.page_jsp._jspService(page_jsp.java:91)
>    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Of course I have the information in my web.xml that the welcome page is set to

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/page.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

if I were to remove this part from the web.xml would I be able to reach that page or is the problem related to something else? In the end I would like to reach different interfaces by providing links like this:

//ip-address:8080/App/mobile_page.jsp
//ip-address:8080/App/browser_page.jsp

Thanks for any input. 
Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is telling that the `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` is returning `null`. This means that the `FacesContext` is not been created. The one who is responsible for that is the `FacesServlet`. This in turn means that the `FacesServlet` is not been invoked at all.

To invoke the `FacesServlet` you need to ensure that the request URL matches the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in the `web.xml`.

You seem to have mapped the `FacesServlet` on `/faces/*`. So, you need to open the page by http://ip-address:8080/App/faces/page.jsp and thus not by http://ip-address:8080/App/page.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSF you should not go directly to the JSP pages but through the handler (faces/* or *.jsf)

Comment: I don't really see how that answer my question. Is this what you are talking about:
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
But the problem is I can't go into that page directly anymore.